# RxSwift operator for transforming Observable<[T]> to Observable<T> by taking first element

Tags: arrays, swift, rx-swift

Currently I do something like this:

```
Observable.just([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .flatMapLatest {
    numbers in
    guard number = numbers.first else {
      return Objservable.empty()
    }
    return Observable.just(number)
  }
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this or any prebuilt operators I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you implemented it is absolutely correct. I'd simply have used `flatMap` in place of `flatMapLatest` as it is a more general operator and we don't need the special logic of `flatMapLatest`.

You could create your own operator that applies to observables that are of type `Collection`.

```
extension Observable where Element : Collection {
  func mapFirst() -> Observable<Element.Iterator.Element> {
    return self.flatMap { elements in
      guard number = numbers.first else {
        return Objservable.empty()
      }
      return Observable.just(number)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: flatMap will “unwrap” one layer of observable. If we’d have use map, the resulting observable would have had type `Observable<Observable<Element>>`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is quite good, you can eg. move it into extension and it'll be more general.
But if you really want to do this other way: you can take a look at [RxOptionals](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxOptional) and use it like:

```
Observable.just([1, 2, 3, 4])
        .filterEmpty()
        .map { $0.first }
        .filterNil()
```